# In jQuery do an each loop inside of specific items

Tags: jquery

I have HTML markup like this:

```
<div class="FullBox">

 <div class="totalPrice"></div>

 <div class="item">
  <div class="title">Item 1</div>
  <div class="price">$35</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="title">Item 2</div>
  <div class="price">$58.99</div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="FullBox">

 <div class="totalPrice"></div>

 <div class="item">
  <div class="title">Item 3</div>
  <div class="price">$22</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="title">Item 4</div>
  <div class="price">$32</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to output the total price of each `FullBox` in the `totalPrice` class.

The final HTML should look like this:

```
<div class="FullBox">

 <div class="totalPrice">$93.99</div>

 <div class="item">
  <div class="title">Item 1</div>
  <div class="price">$35</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="title">Item 2</div>
  <div class="price">$58.99</div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="FullBox">

 <div class="totalPrice">$54</div>

 <div class="item">
  <div class="title">Item 3</div>
  <div class="price">$22</div>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <div class="title">Item 4</div>
  <div class="price">$32</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I tried this to start:

```
$('.FullBox').each(function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('.price').html();
  });
});
```

But that gets the price of every `.price` element on the page, i'm not sure how to group it and then assign it to the specific div that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of printing each price individually, add them to a counter. Also you need to limit the **.item** selector to the scope of its parent FullBox, so I use `$(this).find("item")` instead of `$(".item")`

```
var counter;

$('.FullBox').each(function() {
  counter=0;
  $(this).find('.item').each(function() {
    //console.log($(this).find('.price').html();
    counter=counter + parseFloat($(this).find('.price').html());
  });

  // In the following line (this) refers to the exact parent FullBox:
  $(this).prepend('<div class="totalPrice">$' + counter +'</div>');
});
```

Edit: As you have $ sign before numbers you need to convert them to pure digits before calculations.

```
counter=counter + parseFloat($(this).find('.price').html().replace('$',''))
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
// find all the total price to set the html of
$('.totalPrice').html(function(){
                // get the closest fullbox for the total, and find all the prices
  var $prices = $(this).closest('.FullBox').find('.item .price');
  var total = $prices
    // get all the prices without the dollar sign
    .map((_, price) => price.innerHTML.replace('$', ''))
    // get a basic array
    .get()
    // sum the prices, converted to float
    .reduce((sum, price) => sum + parseFloat(price), 0);
  
  // return the total, removing any precision errors
  return '$'+ ( Math.floor( total * 100 ) / 100 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="FullBox">

  <div class="totalPrice"></div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Item 1</div>
    <div class="price">$35</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Item 2</div>
    <div class="price">$58.99</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="FullBox">

  <div class="totalPrice"></div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Item 3</div>
    <div class="price">$22</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Item 4</div>
    <div class="price">$32</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what the OP did wrong and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a plain vanilla Javascript solution that instead of just changing the content of `totalPrice` divs also creates them.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.FullBox');

for (const box of boxes) {
  const totalPrice = [...box.querySelectorAll('.price')]
    .map(x => Number(x.textContent.substr(1)))
    .reduce((acc, val) => acc += val);
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'totalPrice';
  div.textContent = `Total: $${totalPrice.toFixed(2)}`;
  box.insertBefore(div, box.firstElementChild);
}
```

```html
<div class="FullBox">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Item 1</div>
    <div class="price">$35</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Item 2</div>
    <div class="price">$58.99</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="FullBox">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Item 3</div>
    <div class="price">$22</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Item 4</div>
    <div class="price">$32</div>
  </div>
</div>
```